# Docker container stops after starting with systemd "docker run"

Tags: docker, systemd, docker-container

I've looked at : [Docker and systemd - service stopping after 10 seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29034381/docker-and-systemd-service-stopping-after-10-seconds)
and [Docker containers shut down after systemd start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30505405/docker-containers-shut-down-after-systemd-start?rq=1) , but still can't figure out how to get my docker container to start using systemd and not close out.

My psim.service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=My process
After=docker.service
Requires=docker.service

[Service]
ExecStart=docker run --net=host --name psim -it psim
ExecStop=/bin/docker stop psim
ExecStopPost=/bin/docker rm psim

[Install]
WantedBy=local.target
```

When I use

> "docker run --net=host --name psim -dit psim"

with the detached flag, the container will start but immediately stop and remove itself after a few seconds. If I use either of the following without the detached '-d' flag:

> docker run --net=host --name psim -it psim
>
> docker run --net=host --name psim -a STDOUT -it psim

the container won't start at all using systemd, but will start normally if I run that command without systemd. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Just realized it works if I remove the "-i" flag.

Comment: put the detailed answer here

Comment: The `-i` stands for `--interactive` which is documented to mean " Keep STDIN open even if not attached."  Interactive mode doesn't make sense in the context of running a service in the background.